# MRS and IC : The language sounds contradictory

Tags: microeconomics, utility

The MRS$_{xy}$ is defined as $\left(-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ and Nicholson/Snyder (NS) writes it as *the amount of $x$ we can trade for $y$ while remaining equally well off*.

However, the analytical definition however tells something different, that in a sufficiently close neighbourhood of $(x,y)$, $y\mp \left(-\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = m(x \pm 1) + c$, which can be interpreted as: the amount of $y$ we need to give or get (trade off) for a unit of $x$ (while remaining equally well off).

The two statements sound contradictory, the first one says we need to exchange $x$ at the MRS for every unit of $x$ and the second one says quite the opposite, that we substitute $x$ at the MRS for every unit of $y$.

Is it a mistake in the book by NS?

Comment: Can you specify the reference? I have the 10th edition of NS here and it contains no such verbatim phrase.

Comment: @VARulle Fig. 3.2, Page 92, 11th Ed. NS: *The curve $U_1$ represents those combinations of $x$ and $y$ from which the individual derives the same utility. **The slope of this curve represents the rate at which the individual is willing to trade $x$ for $y$ while remaining equally well off.** This slope (or, more properly, the negative of the slope) is termed the marginal rate of substitution. In the figure, the indifference curve is drawn on the assumption of a diminishing marginal rate of substitution.*

Comment: Well, "*the rate at which the individual is willing to trade x for y*" is not the same as "*the amount of x we can trade for y*"...

Comment: I guess there is a typo in "*we need to exchange x at the MRS for every unit of x*".

Comment: I used to use NS for a micro class. The book has quite some (minor) mistakes & typo's. I guess this is one of them. $dy/dx$ measures how much of $y$ we need to give up to obtain an additional unit of $x$, keeping utility fixed.

Comment: @tdm, but is this inconsistent with "the rate at which the individual is willing to trade $x$ for $y$"? After all, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ also measures how much of $y$ we need to receive to give up a unit of $x$. If I am willing to trade my car for 3 bicycles, isn't then my $MRS_{cars,bicycles}=3$?

Comment: @VARulle I don't think there can be a consensus as this seems to be more semantics related than logic. Personally, however, I would read it as "the rate at which the individual is willing to trade x for *one unit* of $y$". In other words, I would interpret it as: how much do I need to give away of $x$ to get 1 more unit of $y$ (and keeping utility fixed). This would then be the inverse of $dy/dx$. (I'm not a native English speaker though).

Comment: @VARulle Well I think it does satisfy the case when you get (receive) $y$ in exchange for $x$. This is precisely why I used the $\pm, \mp$ in my post instead of just $+$ or $-$. (If you have to give up one unit of $y$ for every MRS units of $x$, then $m \to \frac{1}{m} = \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\text{MRS}}$.

Comment: @tdm Either interpretation takes care of both cases: give and get. This is essentially what I tried to describe with the use of $\pm, \mp$ in my post. (In NS's interpretation, we would do something like I pointed in my previous comment.) So I think there can be a consensus.

Comment: I think we should continue this discussion at the English language SE...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. The verbatime citation is *The slope of this curve represents the rate at which the individual is willing to trade $x$ for $y$ while remaining equally well off.*

*To trade $x$ for $y$* here means to give up some $\Delta x$ to receive $\Delta y$ per unit of $\Delta x$. Letting $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$ the rate is $-\frac{dy}{dx}=MRS_{xy}$.

Comment: Let the utility function of a person be $U(x,y) = 2x + y$. We can probably agree that $|MRS_{xy}| = 2/1$. Would you say the person is willing to trade 2 units of $x$ for a unit of $y$? Or even that the person is willing to trade $x$ for $y$ at a 2:1 ratio?

Comment: @Giskard, no, 2 units of $y$ for a unit of $x$, as I wrote.

Comment: Where did you write this? Seems to me like you wrote "*To trade $x$ for $y$ means to give up some $\Delta x$ to receive $\Delta y$*." and then you implied the rate of trading was equal to the marginal rate of substitution? And "*some* $\Delta x$" implies this is the quantity of $x$ traded?

Comment: @Giskard, exactly. But I don't understand your problem with this. I'm not a native English speaker, so maybe I'm unclear or wrong, but where exactly?

Comment: Neither am I :) But I believe "to trade specified_quantity of $x$ for $y$" implies the same slope as "to trade $\frac{1}{\text{specified_quantity}}$ of $y$ for $x$". The difference in trading direction is, in my opinion, the basis of the question.

Comment: @Giskard, well, I trusted the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_rate_of_substitution#As_the_slope_of_indifference_curve stating that *MRS of X for Y is the amount of Y which a consumer can exchange for one unit of X locally* (substituting "trade" for "exchange").

Comment: But this is the other direction, trading an amount of $Y$ for $X$, not the direction of trading an amount of $X$ for $Y$.

Comment: @Giskard: But the *direction* is not important. I can always receive or give up some amount of either good. The question is, of which good do I receive or give up *one unit*. Then the compensating amount of the other good (given up or received) is the MRS. Granted, this was not very clear in my answer, so I edited it accordingly now.

Comment: "*The question is, of which good do I receive or give up one unit.*" This was also the point I was making.

Comment: As we are considering the "derivative" of $y$ with respect to $x$, you look at how much $y$ changes at the margin when $x$ increases at the margin. So, the natural interpretation would be indeed: At the margin, how much $Y$ (in terms of $X$) would I trade (give up) for  $X$.  But, indeed, the direction of trade ultimately doesn't matter, because the relationship is symmetric via the inverse.

Comment: @BrsG Well the direction is under control if I have to say. This is precisely why I used the $\pm, \mp$ in my post and included both *give and get* in my interpretation.

Comment: @BrsG, I don't want to be nitpicking, but this is not the "natural" way of reading a derivative. The limit in the definition is a two-sided limit, so the $\Delta x$ can have either sign.